# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, election-2012

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://serverfault.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Community authoring an original post? For $DIETY sake, someone teach these devs about least-permission :)

Comment: Jokes, of course. Please don't perma-ban me.

Comment: 2 positions seems a little light.  Unless nobody's up for re-election?   Are we just filling Chopper3's post and adding one more?

Comment: Or just covering for me ;)

Comment: Chopper3 *was* a flag-handling fiend after all.

Comment: Just been having a look at the candidates so far and have to say, it's not going to be easy to decide where my votes go. At some point or other I've "disagreed" with all of them but they're all good candidates.

Comment: ... OK really, who downvotes the community elections post? <Foamy-the-squirrel> I want names people! **Give Me Names!** </Foamy-the-squirrel>

Comment: [ServerFault Moderator Elections -- Useful Statistics](http://se.awio.com/election.html) <-- Click on ServerFault under completed elections, it's pulling 2012's data :)

Answer (score 13):

I think we definitely need a third slot - With Chopper3 stepping down we're effectively only adding one moderator position, and from the cheap seats it seems that we need additional manpower (perhaps not to handle the moderation load, but to keep the per-moderator workload low enough that our moderators can continue to be active participants on the main site).

My understanding is that a third position can/will be opened up after the election (and filled by the #3 person in the race) "if needed", but in our particular case I think holding a 3-position election (and filling the fourth slot on an "if needed" basis) may make more sense.

Just my $3.50

---

[See also This Question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/2544/32986).

Comment: I have to agree. Given how overworked the mods seem to be at times, I don't think its a job I would want to take on right now with these proposed changes.

Comment: @RobMoir see I'm willing to take on moderation, but not to the exclusion of what I enjoy about the site (answering interesting questions, schooling newbies on why we don't use consumber 5-port hubs in enterprise infrastructure, and hanging out in chat) -- worst case I figure I could do moderation-by-calendar and alternate days.

Comment: Is this need for a third across the board or is the problem confined to only some time zones? If the latter then that should be considered when choosing the candidate.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Without a historical trend of the mod queue it would be hard to say, but my impression is there's "enough junk" that mods spend more time doing mod-things (cleanup, migrations, spam-fighting) than answering questions/voting/etc. ; In either case though I think we need to add more than one (net) moderator position...

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - if you take a look at here: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2551/ - there is a huge gap in the # of moderators avaliable during when you and I are awake :(

Comment: @Mark, that hadn't been posted when I asked the question but you're right, "our" period is the emptiest.